# Row gets duplicated after delete from ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, notifydatasetchanged

I know there are already a lot of questions pertaining to this same issue.

Mine looks a bit weird! I have a custom adapter for ListView where I pass an ArrayList of a Model. I have a Context Menu set for this List where on clicking delete, I need to delete the row from ListView (refreshing then and there).

I am calling `xxxxx.remove(info.position)` and then `listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, but it duplicates the last row that was present in the ListView.

Here's the code:

Adapter for ListView:

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Context context;
private final ArrayList<ListModel> itemsArrayList;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListModel> itemsArrayList) {

    super(context, R.layout.viewlistitems, itemsArrayList);
    this.context = context;
    this.itemsArrayList = itemsArrayList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //Get rowView from inflater
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlistitems, parent, false);
    }
    else
        rowView = convertView;

    // 3. Get the two text view from the rowView
    TextView listNameView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.listName);

    listNameView.setTypeface(ViewListActivity.segoe);
    listDateView.setTypeface(ViewListActivity.openSansLightIt);

    String listName1 = itemsArrayList.get(position).getListName();
    String listName2 = listName1.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + listName1.substring(1);


    listNameView.setText(listName2);

    return rowView;
}
```

}

ContextMenu:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
      if (v.getId()==R.id.ListView01) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        menu.setHeaderTitle(todoItems.get(info.position).getListName());
        String[] menuItems = {"Delete"};
        for (int i = 0; i<menuItems.length; i++) {
          menu.add(Menu.NONE, i, i, menuItems[i]);
        }
      }
    }

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();

    if(item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
    Toast.makeText(this,
            todoItems.get(info.position).getListName() + " deleted!",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    todoItems.remove(info.position);

    //newList.invalidateViews();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
     return true;
    }
```

Unable to fix this bug since 1 day! Any idea why this could be happening or what's causing it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I finally resolved this.
I used `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` to invalidate the current adapter, and set a new adapter with my modified list. Worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of this:**

```
if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    // Get rowView from inflater
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlistitems, parent, false);
    }
    else
        rowView = convertView;
```

**Try this:**

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// Get rowView from inflater
rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlistitems, parent, false);
```

and Also you remove item then do not tell the Adapter class that you remove item because Adapter item as same as `temsArrayList`

So, create one method in Adapter class and pass this new arraylist.

```
private viod methodName(arraylist list)
{
temsArrayList=list;
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

then you do not need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
    Call `adapter.methodName(newArraylist)`

Comment: Tried your suggestion just now, but it still didn't work. Same behavior as earlier. Included this:     `void updateData(ArrayList<ListModel> newList) {
     this.itemsArrayList = newList;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
    }` and called this method on adapter after changing dataset.

Comment: Also, the listview does get updated, it's just that after the selected row is deleted, the last row from the list gets duplicated to cover the space.

Comment: also inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewlistitems, null);

Comment: Tried this as well. Extended BaseAdapter, added relevant methods. Still the same behavior. This is so annoying, nothing seems to work..

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue, i was looking for a solution since 2 days.
i finally discover that it is an XML problem not a java problem.
the problem is in the ListView height, it had a value of "wrap_content", i changed it to "match_parent". and the problem was solved.
and then i found a better solution, it is better to put your ListView inside a LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">
                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_topups"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

so as i said my problem was about the height, hope yours too, peace.